# having issues with css animation

Tags: css

Just created an animation but it is not working I want it to make it side from right to left but it is not working can anyone help me out

```
**https://jsfiddle.net/pvoytah3/**
```

Comment: Are you doing this as a learning experience? If so, keep trying, if not... take a look at animate.css: https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: I did i did used but that one is limited as I have 2 animation n same line i will come from behing  from 2 side as like it wil pop up behind the selected div this animation is not avaialble in animate css

Comment: You should include the relevant code in the question... See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you used .active .leftanm2 and .lefttanm2 is not inside .active.
Second: define position in absolute in .lefttanm2 instead inside keyframe animation.

```
.leftanm2 {
  position: absolute;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: slideleft2;
}

@keyframes slideleft2 {
  from {
    right: -51%;
  }

  to {
    left: 0%;
  }
}
```

PD: you can use margin instead position is better for smooth transitions

Comment: this is being used in parrallax so that is why i used active class and it worked problem is this i want it to animate from riht to left like came from right towards left this is not happening let me update the js fiddle code